Minecraft Forge Modding: Gradle Dependency Resolution Issues for Multiple Mods
I’m working on a Minecraft Forge mod for version 1.19.2, and I’m encountering issues resolving dependencies for other mods required in my project. The mods in question include Tensura, Create, Geckolib, ManasCore, and TerraBlender.
Despite adding the recommended Maven repositories and dependency configurations, Gradle fails to resolve them. Here’s what I’ve tried and the issues I’m encountering:

Dependencies Failing to Resolve
Here are some of the error messages I’m receiving:

Could not find com.github.manasmods:ManasCore:1.19.2-2.1.4.3_mapped_official_1.19.2.
Could not find com.github.manasmods:tensura:1.19.2-1.0.0.7_mapped_official_1.19.2.
Could not find software.bernie.geckolib:geckolib-forge-1.19:3.1.40_mapped_official_1.19.2.
Could not find com.github.glitchfiend:TerraBlender-forge:1.19.2-2.0.1.162_mapped_official_1.19.2.
Could not find com.simibubi.create:create:1.19.2-0.5.1.i_mapped_official_1.19.2.

Here is the repositories block I’m using in my build.gradle:
repositories {
    // ForgeGradle automatically adds the Forge maven and Maven Central for you.
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
    maven { url = 'https://maven.parchmentmc.org/' }

    // For libraries stored locally in the `lib` folder.
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }

    // CurseForge Maven for mod dependencies.
    exclusiveContent {
        forRepository {
            maven {
                url "https://cursemaven.com/"
            }
        }
        filter {
            includeGroup "curse.maven"
        }
    }

    // Specific Maven repositories for required mods and libraries.
    maven { url = 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/geckolib3/geckolib/maven' }
    maven { url = 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/manasmods/manascore/maven/' }
    maven { url = 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/manasmods/tensura/maven/' }
    maven { url = 'https://jitpack.io/' }
}

Here’s the relevant part of the dependencies block:
dependencies {
    minecraft "net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2-43.4.0"
    implementation fg.deobf("com.github.manasmods:ManasCore:1.19.2-2.1.4.3")
    implementation fg.deobf("com.github.manasmods:tensura:1.19.2-1.0.0.7")
    implementation fg.deobf("software.bernie.geckolib:geckolib-forge-1.19:3.1.40")
    implementation fg.deobf("com.github.glitchfiend:TerraBlender-forge:1.19.2-2.0.1.162")
    implementation fg.deobf("com.simibubi.create:create:1.19.2-0.5.1.i")
}

for my mapping I am using parchment version 2022.08.14-1.19.2
And another thing to note it says they all fail or can't be found but I'm able to import classes and use stuff from all of them except create
